# Cast ArrayList to a Generic Abstract Collection

Tags: java, generics, casting

How do I cast an ArrayList to a Generic Collection? I have highlighted the problem in "SearchListener" with "<-----------This Doesn't work!!!!"

I'm reading about Class.cast(o) but I'm not understanding how to apply it here.

```
public abstract class MyTufinCollection<T> extends AbstractCollection<T> implements ListModel<String>{
```

}

```
public class SearchListener<T,C extends MyTufinCollection<T>> implements DocumentListener{

private JList jlist;
private C staticCollectionOfTypeT;
private List<Predicate<T>> predicateList = new ArrayList<>();
 //get the String fields, and build Predicate from them.. add to predicateList.



public SearchListener(JList jlist, List<Predicate<T>> predicateList, C collection) {        
    this.jlist = jlist;
    this.staticCollectionOfTypeT=collection;
    this.predicateList=predicateList;
}

@Override
public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent de) {
    filter();
}

@Override
public void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent de) {
    filter();
}

@Override
public void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent de) {
    filter();
}

private void filter() {
    jlist.setModel((ListModel)staticCollectionOfTypeT);
    C items = (C) jlist.getModel();

    Stream<T> itemStream = items.stream().filter(x ->{
        Stream<Predicate<T>> predicateStream= predicateList.stream();
        return predicateStream.map(predicate -> predicate.test(x)).reduce((a,b)->a && b).get();
    });
    ArrayList<T> collect = itemStream.collect(Collectors.toCollection(ArrayList::new));
    C name = (C)collect; // <-----------This Doesn't work!!!!
    jlist.setModel((ListModel)name);
}
```

}

Comment: And why do you think it should work?

Comment: How can I make this work? Create a new MyTufinCollection() convenience class and use Collectors.toCollection(new MyTufinCollection(){...})? Or is there a better way?

Answer (score 0):

Casting doesn't mean *transforming A into B*. It only means *reducing the view*.

So if you have an `A` and this `A` is also a `B`, for example because it extends from it. Then you can reduce the view to this `A` by casting it to `B`. For example a `List` extends from `Collection`, thus you can cast it to `Collection`. But a `String` does not extend from `Collection`, you can't cast it.

In your case you are trying to cast an `ArrayList` to a `C`, but `C extends MyTufinCollection<T>`. `ArrayList` doesn't extend from that. It is like trying to cast an `ArrayList` to a `HashSet`, both are `Collection`s but it doesn't work for obvious reasons.

For example `MyTufinCollection` problably has some stuff that `ArrayList` does not have, how should Java automatically determine what to do. It can't, casting won't work. You will need to **explicitly** give a conversion-method.

The term is the [is-a](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Is-a) principle. You can read more about **casting** in [JLS§5.5.1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.5.1):

> If `S` (source) is a class type:
>
> If `T` (target) is a class type, then either `|S| <: |T|`, or `|T| <: |S|`.
>   **Otherwise**, a **compile-time error** occurs.
>
> Furthermore, if there exists a supertype `X` of `T`, and a supertype `Y` of `S`, such that both `X` and `Y` are provably **distinct** parameterized types ([§4.5](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.5)), and that the **erasures** of `X` and `Y` are the **same**, a **compile-time error** occurs.

Comment: yes, but I can't make a new C because it is generic. How do you overcome this?

Comment: Why can't you create new instances of `C`? You know that it is at least `MyTufinCollection<T>`, so you can use all methods provided by that class. I mean you will need to ask yourself how an `ArrayList` can become a `MyTufinCollection`. Does the `MyTufinCollection` offer some kind of `add` method? Then you can simply add the elements of the `ArrayList`.